# read pdf form data using iTextSharp: empty values

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm reading a PDF module using iTextSharp and it's working quite good. I don't know why but, when I try to read the PDF fields using GetField() method some fields correctly filled on PDF file are returned as empty (value = "").

Do you know why? Are there some other way to extract values from PDF fields?

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fileName), null);
pdfFormFields = pdfReader.AcroFields;

foreach (var field in pdfFormFields.Fields) {
     _logger.Error("Field: " + field.Key + " - Value: " + pdfFormFields.GetField(field.Key.ToString()));
}
```

This is the output:

```
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG1[0].SITO_TUMORE_PRIMITIVO[0] - Value: Stomaco
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG1[0].ALTRO_SITO_TUMORE_PRIMITIVO[0] - Value: cervice
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG1[0].IST_PRIM_SECOND[0] - Value: su secondario
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG1[0].STADIAZIONE[0] - Value: IIa
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG2[0].OCTREOSCAN_Ga-PET[0] - Value: Negativo
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG2[0].FUNZIONANTE[0] - Value: No
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG2[0].CgA_INIZIO_TERAPIA[0] - Value: 1.00000000
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG2[0].CgA_VAL_RIFERIMENTO[0] - Value: 
PDFReader.PDFRead - Field: modulo1[0].BASALE_PAG2[0].ACIDO5_VAL_RIFERIMENTO[0] - Value:
```

tnx, 
Andrea

Comment: maybe a code snippet would help

Comment: do you have code that sets the fields for example something like this  AcroFields pdfFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;       pdfFields.SetField("SomeFieldName",. . . .);

Comment: No, because users fill that PDF using Acrobat Reader and then they upload the files to a web application that parse the pdf.

Comment: ok I think for me to really see what's goin on I would need to see a bit more code..

Answer (score 1):

This code should give you the Content of all Fields in C#:

```
   public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

                    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                    {
                        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                        string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                        text.Append(currentText);
                    }
                    pdfReader.Close();
                }
                return text.ToString();
            }
            private static string GetFormFieldNames(PdfReader pdfReader)
            {
                return string.Join("\r\n", pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
                                               .Select(x => x.Key).ToArray());
            }

            private static string GetFormFieldNamesWithValues(PdfReader pdfReader)
            {
                return string.Join("\r\n", pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
                                               .Select(x => x.Key + "=" +
                                                pdfReader.AcroFields.GetField(x.Key))
                                               .ToArray());
            }
            private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               var reader = new PdfReader(@"Direction_to_your.pdf");
               AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
               txtBox1.Text = GetFormFieldNamesWithValues(reader); 
               reader.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work change to fit your code
  this would create more of a Listner for the pdf you created.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create));
```